# Facebook App Page missing “Go To App” button

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I have a facebook canvas app that I associated with an existing Facebook page but I don't have a "Go to app" button in the facebook page.

I think that the problem comes from the configuration (of the facebook page or the facebook app) but I can't find what is wrong.

> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4mppfj26dr6v5c7/AAAfthrlfke63IgLJJEm900na

I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas#app-page), the canvas app works and the canvas app is associated with the facebook page but I don't see any information about more configuration needed.

What's necessary to configure to have the "Go to app" button ? Or am I missing something else ?

I see some other similar threads but no one help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the page in the category App Page?

Comment: Yes, it's in the category "Brands & Products" and "App Page".